# Enable a disabled button and click it with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a disabled button I want to click with Javascript.
The following function works in Chrome but not in Firefox.
The problem with Firefox: Firefox javascript is too slow.
The button is still disabled if the code wants to click it. How to click the button when it is enabled?

```
function enable_and_click() {
    document.getElementById('button1').disabled=false;
    document.getElementById('button1').click();
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/zMnDj/ What version of Firefox are you using? Can you try reproducing the problem on jsFiddle?

Comment: You've written "disabled" wrong. You can reproduce the problem with this one: http://jsfiddle.net/zMnDj/2/ I'm using Firefox 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
document.getElementById('button1').removeAttribute('disabled');
document.getElementById('button1').click();
```

**Update**

Using jQuery, a cross browser solution would be:

```
var element = $('#button1');
element.removeAttr('disabled');
element.click();
```

Comment: Sorry does not solve the problem look here with Firefox 7: http://jsfiddle.net/zMnDj/3/

Comment: @therealmarv I reckon it's a problem with FF7 (works in FF9), are you able to use jQuery? If so [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zMnDj/14/) should work cross browser

Comment: Thanks this seems the most cleanest solution. I use JQuery BTW: You've forgotten `#` in code: http://jsfiddle.net/zMnDj/15/ Please edit your answer and then I can confirm it works ;-)